# Wordpress twenty seventeen: make the background's position "top" instead of "center"

Tags: html, css, center, background-position

I am trying to make my background image (the header media) positioned at the top of the screen, rather than centered. In other words, I don't want the top to be clipped out: only the bottom. This could be as simple as "background-position: center top", but I spent an hour trying to find where to implement this code, with no success...

The website is [www.latelierdegaia.ch](http://www.latelierdegaia.ch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all its not a background .. its an image which is positioned as u can see in screen shot. http://jmp.sh/MYGDtcX

make this height auto and it will fix the issue hopefully.

```
.has-header-image .custom-header-media img, .has-header-video .custom-header-
 media video, .has-header-video .custom-header-media iframe, .has-header-
 image:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page):not(.home) .custom-header-media img{

 height:auto;

 }
```

Comment: Thanks a million! That solved the problem! And I would never have found that out by myself.